# Sending Slack message when a value from sheet is in next week (Apps Script - Slack incoming webhooks)

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, slack, slack-api

I'm trying to utilize slack incoming webhooks to let my teammates know the information of new hires written in sheet at the designated time.

At 3rd column, I write the first date of each new hire.
And want to share info of new hires a week before the first date, at certain time.

For example, if there are 3 new hires on 2nd Monday of August, I'd like to let slack bot share the info at 1st Monday of August, 10:00am KST.

Looks like I need to use formatted_date value to send out auto message a week earlier.
How would I make it possible?

```js
<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to schedule a message on Slack using an app you won't be able to do it using a webhook. I'd recommend using a bot token and making an API call to [chat.scheduleMessage](https://api.slack.com/methods/chat.scheduleMessage) instead.